# Google Spreadsheet Check From What Cell VLOOKUP() Returns

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets, spreadsheet, gs-vlookup

Is there a way to return the cell from which VLOOKUP() gets its value?

For instance:

```
________A_____|__B__|
1 | Mouse     |  1  |
2 | Keyboard  |  2  |
3 | Headset   |  3  |
4 | HDD       |  4  |
```

=VLOOKUP("Mouse",A1:B4,2,FALSE) --would return "1".

Is there a way to make it return "B1" instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH("Mouse",A1:A4,0),2, 1)
```

How this works...
The address part captures the cell address and is as follows

```
=Address(row,column,abs)
```

The match function returns Row number, 2 is the second coloumn - you will have to change as per your requirement. The abs (absolute) can be 1,2,3,4 or omitted....try changing it to understand....

Comment: I had to replace the commas(',') with semicolons(';') to get the formula work in google sheets.

Comment: @SheikhFaisalMiskhat this is not true. It depends on the local settings of your spreadsheet!

Comment: @marcomow true. based on my local settings it worked for me with the ';'.